# Calling Istio VirtualService via http from Salesforce

Tags: google-cloud-platform, salesforce, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, istio-gateway

We use istio-ingress with Gateway and VirtualService. Istio has been installed with the use of `IstioOperator`. Istio works in private VPC in GKE. Ingress traffic comes via
GCP external load balancer.

When calling the endpoint via curl or some publicly accessible API test software everything is OK, e.g.

```
curl -sv  -HHost:host.name.pl "http://[redacted]/api/health/livez"                                                           
*   Trying [redacted]:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [redacted] (redacted) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/health/livez HTTP/1.1
> Host:host.name.pl
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 2
< date: Thu, 20 May 2021 11:35:15 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
< server: istio-envoy
< 
* Connection #0 to host [redacted] left intact
ok%
```

But when the callout to the virtual service is carrying out from Salesforce Apex:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('http://[some IP]/api/health/livez');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Host', '[some host]');
request.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
request.setTimeout(12000);
System.debug('### request: ' + (request));
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

System.debug('### response: ' + response);
for(string s : response.getHeaderKeys()){
    System.debug('### header: ' + s + '  ' + response.getHeader(s));
}
System.debug('### response: ' + response.getStatus());
System.debug('### response: ' + response.getStatusCode());
```

then the response is as follows:

```
02:35:52.21 (64126592)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|### header: X-Cache  MISS from proxy-fra.net.salesforce.com
02:35:52.21 (64153199)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|### header: Server  istio-envoy
02:35:52.21 (64167840)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|### header: X-Cache-Lookup  MISS from proxy-fra.net.salesforce.com:8080
02:35:52.21 (64181660)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|### header: Connection  keep-alive
02:35:52.21 (64194536)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|### header: Content-Length  0
02:35:52.21 (64207171)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|### header: Date  Thu, 20 May 2021 09:35:52 GMT
02:35:52.21 (64236542)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|### response: Not Found
02:35:52.21 (64293430)|USER_DEBUG|[19]|DEBUG|### response: 404
```

We do not know why X-Cache and X-Cache-Lookup is added (proxy-fra.net.salesforce.com:8080 it's not our host:port of course) to the response and what to do with that. We do not know whether either it's a problem on salesforce side or istio side.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, It could be better, if you ask this question on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It turned out that regardless of whether you set up a Host using setHeader, Salesfore would overwrite it with the value from the request url. Hence the error. We were confused by this strange answer about X-CACHE. We solved the problem by using the dns name (compatible with the expected host) in the request with SF.